# Иконка приложения Qt [Mac]

Tags: qt, qt5

Делаю всё по [мануалу](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html).
Иконка лежит в отдельной папке `source` в папке проекта.
В файле `project.pro` прописан полный путь к файлу:

```
ICON = /Users/arsenyspiridonov/Documents/NITA/Optimization of the total delay time/Aircraft Algorithm Pack/source/600x600_45d.icns
```

Ни в доке, ни в Finder, ни в заголовке окна приложения ничего нет

Comment: Соберите релизный вариант приложения. Наталкивался на проблему, когда иконка не цепляется к дебажному бинарнику

Comment: Попробуйте запихнуть иконку в каталог, в пути к которому не будет пробелов. Или добавить к пути кавычки.

Answer (score 1):

Если провести небольшой эксперимент, то видим, что qmake путь с пробелами воспринимает как несколько разных путей и в переменную ICON записывается массив строк.

```
ICON = /Users/arsenyspiridonov/Documents/NITA/Optimization of the total delay time/Aircraft Algorithm Pack/source/600x600_45d.icns

for(a, ICON) : message($${a})
```

Результат:

```
Project MESSAGE: /Users/arsenyspiridonov/Documents/NITA/Optimization
Project MESSAGE: of
Project MESSAGE: the
Project MESSAGE: total
Project MESSAGE: delay
Project MESSAGE: time/Aircraft
Project MESSAGE: Algorithm
Project MESSAGE: Pack/source/600x600_45d.icns
```

Что бы такое предотвратить, необходимо взять путь в двойные кавычки:

```
ICON = "/Users/arsenyspiridonov/Documents/NITA/Optimization of the total delay time/Aircraft Algorithm Pack/source/600x600_45d.icns"
```

Или использовать функцию `quote`

```
ICON = $$quote(/Users/arsenyspiridonov/Documents/NITA/Optimization of the total delay time/Aircraft Algorithm Pack/source/600x600_45d.icns)
```

Тогда в переменную ICON действительно записывается одно строковое значение.

Comment: error: No rule to make target `/Users/arsenyspiridonov/Documents/NITA/Optimization of the total delay time/Aircraft Algorithm Pack/source/600x600_45d.icns', needed by `AircraftAlgorithmPack.app/Contents/Resources/600x600_45d.icns'.  Stop.

Comment: Иконка лежит в папке проекта вместе с исходниками

Comment: тогда пишите: ``ICON = 600x600_45d.icns``

Comment: Та же самая ошибка